# Export to CSV in Javascript

Tags: javascript, csv

I have a requirement in my web-app where in I have to export data in a html table to a csv file. The html data table is written using the [Datatables](http://datatables.net/) plugin.

There is a [Table Tools](http://datatables.net/extras/tabletools/) offered for the above data table which does the CSV,PDF,XLS export on the client side. The drawback is that the above plugin uses flash which is not a favorable solution.

I also looked at an alternate pure javascript based client side solution [here](https://gist.github.com/syntagmatic/2202660)

This does not seem to work as well as I am not able to specify a file name.

On searching forums I learnt that in pure javascript I will  not be able to create a file and name it. (I guess the File System API in HTML5 might solve this once all browsers evolve / accept HTML5 standards)

Given this situation, I was curious if the following is possiible:

1. data to be exported ready on my client side
2. Can I make an ajax call to my server to get a blank csv file and manipulate the same on the client side and append it with the data I have on my client side ?

Apart from the above proposed solution and a pure server side approach are there any other solutions possible ?

Answer (score 0):

I think a better *hybrid* solution would involve a general server-side csv generation script, fed with the exported-ready data from the clientside (either filtered, manually inserted or whatever you need to do on the client) by means of a simple redirect (GET params) or form submission (POST params).

With GET params you can avoid changing you contents structure (i.e. no form and inputs are needed) and go for a pure-javascript *serialization script* that will call your csv generator.

By the way, Flash and HTML5 are the only available solution if you really don't want to mess up with server-side.